# Create array of elements from a given string in MIPS Assembly language

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there any way to make an array consisting of the words, punctuation signs and spaces in a given string? By this I mean, if the given string is `"Hi, I am Lucas"`, obtain an array:

`["Hi", ",", " ", "I", " ", "am", " ", "Lucas"]`

Thanks!

EDIT: So this is   a part of a practice excessive I'm attempting, which is a tokenizer. The final aim is to separate an input string into tokens.(words, punctuation marks and spaces), and print them one per line. So with the example above, the result should be:

Hi

,

I

am

Lucas

Hopefully this makes things a bit more clear.

Comment: yes. (there are multiple ways) ... BTW, the MIPS assembly doesn't have any native type for "array of strings", so you have to be more specific, what you want to receive... do you want array of pointers to substrings, each terminated by zero character (C string)? Or pointers to substrings + their lengths (so you can actually build such table without modifying source string, but you will have no simple way to extract C string from that, except copying letters to new buffer and adding zero terminator) Or array where element is fixed size reserved buffer (like 64 characters) and contains substring

Comment: in the current state the question is "too broad", or "lack of effort", although maybe you are more clueless than effortless, then you should probably do some more examples exercises with MIPS assembly to get better understanding what are "strings" in assembly, how they are stored in memory, and also how "array"-like constructs can be achieved in assembly (neither "array" or "string" is native to CPU, so these are higher concepts achieved by the written code and there are many possible ways how to achieve something like that). Then you should be able to propose some particular solution for it.

Comment: For example, in case of C language for example `const char* wordList[] = {"Hi", ",", " ", "I", " ", "am", " ", "Lucas"};` will produce separate C strings in memory (like `.string "Hi"` taking 3 bytes of memory (2 ASCII chars + zero terminator)) and then it will create single array of memory pointers (addresses), each element containing pointer to particular substring. When you have source data as single string, you will have to copy substrings into new memory, adding zero terminators after each, and remembering start of each in the pointer array.

Comment: after EDIT: no, that didn't make it more clear, you still didn't propose which data structures you want to use. It's still possible to use all three basic ways mentioned in my comment (or something else). For a real world tokenizer (like for compiler) I would keep array of pointers+length, without copying original string data. Which would work well for compilation tasks, but it makes it more tricky for simple printing which expect C-string (MARS/SPIM common service for print wants that) (linux code can use `write` with length explicitly specified) (you don't even mention your target+inputs).